# How to mantain user session after user close the app with framework 7?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I would like to maintain the user session even after a user closes my app. if I logged in my application on my mobile, it should always be logged in whenever I try to access to my application. I don’t know how to start it… Now, when the user do the login I store the email and the password in a local variable in my-app.js. Then I check with a request to my API if the user has the permission and then I show him the index…. but If the user close the app and then start it again I have to do the login. It’s not a good behaviour.
How can I maintein user logged with framework7?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue you can store login status in locastorage or use localforage for more advance storage by DB....

The idea is when user login set a flag variable in storage tell your app is user login or no, if yes, you will handling app to go to needed page, else to login page. also if user click on logout you need to remove storage or update storage flag to be false.

Note: You can save any data you want too.

Code Example:

```
// after success login 
    localStorage.setItem("LoginFlag", true);
    OR
    localforage.setItem('LoginFlag', true).then(function (value) {
    // Do other things once the value has been saved.
    console.log(value);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // This code runs if there were any errors
    console.log(err);
});

// When init app (when run for first time, or close app and open again)
if(localStorage.getItem("LoginFlag")){
   // do somthing
}

OR 
localforage.getItem('LoginFlag').then(function(value) {
    // This code runs once the value has been loaded
    // from the offline store.
    if(!value){// do somthing}
}).catch(function(err) {
    // This code runs if there were any errors
    console.log(err);
});
```

[localforage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/) Also [localforage Github](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) and [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp).

Comment: Thank you Anees :) but How can I put on framework7 the if //when init app(when run for fisrt time?

Comment: I put in myapp.js the if //when init app(when run for fisrt time.. in the pageInit of login.html, but it works partially, because if I open e close for many time, suddenly the app show the index without doing the login

Comment: mmm, I think theirs another issue now, maybe cache issue, or something else..make sure your condition not change some where, and set console.log for open and close app...and see what is resault

Comment: I try to explain me better, If I lunch for the first time the app after doing the build, the app show directly the index without do the login.

Comment: okay, try plz set your code here -like this- `app.on('pageBeforeIn', function(page){
// your code here
    }
});`

Comment: nothing chage, but I saw in the console that the code inside this method after the deploying is not execute, only if I do the logout (I'm inside the app without doing login before)

Comment: I think issue on index init page, you try to redirect from index init page..so that first time not trigger, please try set `init: false` in `var app = new Framework7({
    init: false
});`

Comment: If I put  init:false, I can't see the app and also the method is not exectued

Comment: okay, plz remove it and set this your code in `setTimeout(function(){// your code}, 1000);` in last line in your script file....(Just for test case)

Comment: Hi Aness, thank you for your help :)  I delete the control inside pageInit of the index.html and I leave only one in pageInit of login.html. Now the app start with the login. However, the session is maintained only if the app stays in backroung, if I close the app I have to do the login.. so I don't resolve the issue of session

Comment: Solved, Thank you so much Anees :D